# Replace string while updating sql

Tags: sql

I have table called Empdetails. Here one of column name is loginid. I want to replace loginid if it contain `@s.com`, in few case it has.

```
Loginid
abc@s.com
sdf
ghj
adfgh@j.com
fghjku@s.com
pinky@s.com
```

```
update  Empdetails
set loginid = REPLACE(loginid, '@s.com', '')
where id in (1,6,8,9)
```

If I mistakenly mention id whose loginid does not contain any '@s.com', will throw an error. Is above query is fine

Comment: What happens when you run this query?

Comment: You can add `AND loginid LIKE '%@s.com%'` to the WHERE clause  to keep transaction size down.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the exact error message you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, your query will not end in Error.

The below will only update records which end with '@s.com'

```
update Empdetails
set loginid = REPLACE(loginid, '@s.com', '')
where loginid  like '%@s.com'
```

You don't need to specify ID, you can just use your logic to filter records which you want to update

Comment: Maybe he wants to replace them in that specifics ids. Upvoted anyway

Comment: @Cid edited to just answer the OP's question. Also OP mentions - *I want to replace loginid if it contain @s.com*

Comment: Thanks @cid,@sujipta